# Facing issue with ssh to docker container

Tags: docker, ssh

I am playing around with docker containers and trying to do ssh with the docker containers using the host machine.

So I am creating my docker container using the below docker file.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
LABEL maintainer="Sagar Shroff" version="1.0" type="ubuntu-with-ssh"
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN service ssh restart
EXPOSE 22
USER root
WORKDIR /root
CMD service ssh restart && \
    echo "Enter root's password: " && passwd root && \
    /bin/bash
```

and I run my docker container using the command
`docker run --rm -it -p 1022:22 ssh-ubuntu-example`

After entering the root password I make the container go into background mode by pressing Ctrl+P, Q and then do ssh from my host machine using the command
`ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 1022`

But I am unable to connect

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 1022
root@127.0.0.1's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@127.0.0.1's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@127.0.0.1's password:
root@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Comment: Typically, the ssh daemon doesn't allow remote connections as root.  But it's also really unusual to run sshd in Docker at all: running multiple processes in a container is tricky and maintaining credentials is all but impossible (anyone who has your image has a copy of the host key and can impersonate your server).

Comment: I agree @DavidMaze. I was actually doing some r&d related to ssh before. The tutorials I was referring to required me to download and set up entire vms on my host. So I rather thought about using containers for the point of this tutorial.